# How many Koco are needed per upgrade from Elder Koco?

Tags: sonic-frontiers

The Elder Koko can increase Sonic's speed or ring capacity in exchange for returning lost Koco. How many lost Koco are needed per upgrade?

[image: Talking to Elder Koco]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Sonic Fandom](https://sonic.fandom.com/wiki/Elder_Koco#Overview):

> When Sonic delivers **15 lost Koco** to the Elder Koco, it will thank Sonic by increasing one of his stats, boosting either the hedgehog’s speed or maximum ring count.